# How to evaluate $\int\frac{1}{3+4x+4x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

> How to evaluate
>   $$\int\frac{1}{3+4x+4x^2}\quad ?
> $$

This is what I've done so far:
$$
\frac{1}{4} \int\frac{1}{x^2+x+\frac{3}{4}}
=\frac{1}{4} \int\frac{1}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{1}{2}}
$$

$$ 
y = \frac{1}{a}\arctan\frac{u}{a},\quad \frac{dy}{du} = \frac{1}{a^2 + u^2}
$$
$$
a = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}},\quad
u = (x+\frac{1}{2}),\quad \frac{du}{dx} = 1
$$
so
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot 1
$$

I don't know how to proceed.
Could I also have some help with
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{-4x^2-4x+3}}\quad ?
$$

Comment: $$ x^2 + x + \frac{3}{4} = \left( x + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 +  \frac{1}{2}  $$

Comment: Unrelated note: remember to add a $dx$ at the end of your integrals.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: so is the answer $$\frac{\sqrt2}{4}arctan\sqrt2({x+\frac{1}{2}})$$?

Comment: If you want to check the *answer*, try going to Wolfram Alpha, which can basically calculate everything for you.

Comment: Very minor comment use “\arctan”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What can be done is a double U-Substitution

We have $$\int\frac{1}{3+4x+4x^2}dx$$

By completing the square we see $$\int\frac{1}{3+4x+4x^2}dx = \int\frac{1}{(2x+1)^2+2}dx$$

Now substitute $u = 2x+1$ and $du = 2udx$. Now our integral becomes $$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{u^2+2}du = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{2(\frac{u^2}{2}+1)}du = \frac{1}{4}\int\frac{1}{(\frac{u^2}{2}+1)}du$$

Now we substitute $s = \frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $ds = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}du$
 in the integrand. $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{1}{s^2+1}ds$$

$$\int\frac{1}{s^2+1}ds = \tan^{-1}(s)$$ So we are left with $$\frac{\tan^{-1}(s)}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Back substituting $s = \frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}$, $$\frac{\tan^{-1}(s)}{2\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}})}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Now back substitute $u = 2x+1$ and $$\frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}})}{2\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{2}})}{2\sqrt{2}}$$,

so our final answer is $$\boxed{\frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{2}})}{2\sqrt{2}}+ C}$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**:Complete the squares and use the results

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2 + a^2}dx= \frac{1}{a}\arctan \frac{x}{a}+C $$
and
$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}dx=\arcsin \frac{x}{a}+C$$.